# Wrong Serialization on LINQ Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a LINQ query as that:

```
public List<tblStudent> GetNames()
{
    var result = (from student in db.tblStudents.ToList()
                  select new tblStudent 
                  {
                      StudentID = student.StudentID,
                      StudentName = student.StudentName,
                      Email = student.Email,
                      IsDeleted= student.IsDeleted

                      //tblDepartment = department.tblStudents
                  });
    return result.ToList();
}
```

When I executed that query it gave me a result as that:

[image: My Result]

But I don't want to see *null* values in my result. How I can solve that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't tried it, I'd expect you to be able to configure Json.NET to ignore null values when serializing. Within `ConfigureServices`, write this:

```cs
services.AddJsonFormatters(settings => settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore);
```

Using an anonymous type instead would work too, but that becomes trickier if you have a list where *some* objects have non-null values for certain properties, and other objects have null values. It's good to be aware of both approaches, so you can use whichever one is more appropriate in any situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an anonymous type to return only the desired members when returning the collection from the `ApiController`

For example

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController {

    //...

    public IHttpActionResult MyControllerAction() {
        var result = myService.GetNames()
                    .Select(student => select new { //<-- Note what was done here
                          StudentID = student.StudentID,
                          StudentName = student.StudentName,
                          Email = student.Email,
                          IsDeleted= student.IsDeleted
                      });
        return Ok(result.ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: It threw an error as that:
The name 'Ok' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @HalilŞahin I assumed you were making the call within a `ApiController` as you mentioned Web API based on the tags of the question. To what type does `GetNames()` belong?

Comment: its an ApiController

Comment: @HalilŞahin then the method should exist https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.2#System_Web_Http_ApiController_Ok__1___0_

Comment: @HalilŞahin just to make sure the correct version is being used, is the `ApiController` in an attribute `[ApiController]` as in asp.net-core, or is it used as a base class  like `MyController: ApiController` as in asp.net-web-api-2+

Comment: my project not an .NetCore project. and my current class implemented from an interface. And my Controller extended from ApiController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189720/discussion-between-halil-sahin-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 1):

I just added that line on my `WebApiConfig.cs` and my problem been solved.

```
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```